# A word like "inappropriate", with a less extreme connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes I would like to use the word "inappropriate" when it simply means not *quite* appropriate, but it usually seems to have the connotation of *extremely* not appropriate.

For instance, if I wanted to say a person was touching inappropriately, it might not mean they are doing something lewd (e.g. touching private parts), but rather, sitting too close and touching in a professional environment where it doesn't make much sense.

Or perhaps it's a meeting where a subordinate is dominating a conversation where multiple higher-ups or people more familiar with the topic should be speaking more.  Their speech would not be appropriate, but calling it inappropriate seems to indicate that they were making crass jokes or saying something offensive.

Comment: I think you may be making a faulty assumption about the meaning and severity of the word *inappropriate*

Comment: Your two examples don't seem to have a lot in common. Using 'inappropriate' for the first is... appropriate. Using a word like dominating, or just rude, would suit the second better.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the meaning is back to front. "Inappropriate" used to be a neutral word meaning the opposite of "appropriate", until the Politically Correct Language Police decided to use it as an euphemism for "obscene".

Comment: "inadequate" is more neutral than "inaprpropriate".

Comment: . *Borderline*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the word "inappropriate" has acquired certain connotations. As the question says, particularly in a US business context, it has come to mean something heading towards sexual harassment.

However, I don't think **not appropriate** has these connotations.

Alternatively, just avoid the moral judgement implicit in discussing the appropriateness of the behaviour. If, for example, you describe somebody's behaviour as **unnecessary** or **excessive** ("sitting unnecessarily/excessively close", "taking up an excessive amount of time at the meeting"), the reader can figure out that the person wasn't behaving in an appropriate way.

Comment: I thought of making your point re *not appropriate*. Glad you did. I see it the same way.

Comment: I agree on *unnecessary* for the first example; would you also consider *unjustified* for the second?

Comment: @lserni I don't think I would, though others might. I tend not to think about justification for speaking in a meeting: that would feel like needing to have a reasoned argument for breaking the silence, every time I open my mouth.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see anything wrong with **inappropriate**. From Dictionary.com:

> [**inappropriate**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inappropriate?s=t):
>   not appropriate; not proper or suitable

At the same time, I take your point. Because of its "extremely" negative connotations in some contexts, especially sexual contexts, **inappropriate** seems to have taken on an unnecessarily negative meaning. It seems to be getting a bad rap.

One possible one-word alternative is **improper**. From Dictionary. com:

> [**improper**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/improper?s=ts): not in
>   accordance with propriety of behavior, manners, etc.:
>   *improper conduct at a funeral*; unsuitable or inappropriate, as for the purpose or occasion: *improper attire for a formal dance*.

One could say that it is **improper** for:

- a person to sit too close to and touch another person "in a professional environment where it doesn't make much sense" (although **inappropriate** in your extreme sense could actually apply here, even if the toucher is unaware of it).
- "a subordinate to dominate a conversation where multiple higher-ups or people more familiar with the topic should be speaking more".

The same dynamic that has infected **inappropriate** could infect **improper**, if it has not already done so.

Comment: I think the best answer was alluded to in your definitions: unsuitable.  Maybe not quite as versatile a word as inappropriate, but to me it's definitely a superior word when you don't want to emphasize criticism.

Answer (score 9):

**Uncomfortable**

---

It doesn't have extreme connotations (at least not in my mind) and it fits the scenarios you proposed.

1. *He was uncomfortably close.*
2. *He dominated the conversation with an uncomfortable lack of familiarity.*

Answer (score 7):

**Unprofessional** works quite well in the two examples provided:

- Sitting too close to or touching (which itself has a worse connotation than inappropriate) others is certainly unprofessional behavior.
- It often is unprofessional for a non-expert to be explaining something when experts in the topic are present at the same meeting.

In a number of situations however, **unprofessional** does not mean the same thing as *inappropriate* does.

While I would suggest **unacceptable**, the connotation is at least as extreme as *inappropriate* itself. **Improper** is a decent option.

Perhaps you could use negation. *Not appropriate* means the same thing as inappropriate, but might not have the same connotations that *inappropriate* has. Granted, it isn't a single word, but it seems worth mentioning.

Comment: "Unacceptable behaviour" is definitely worse than "inappropriate behaviour". Unacceptable behaviour is something that gets you fired or put on a final warning; behaviour that's "inappropriate" in the sense of the question gets you a chat with your boss asking if you could try not to do that again, please.

Comment: By the way, I don't think "not appropriate" is an example of litotes: it's a simple negation. Litotes is the use of understatement, usually (but not always) incorporating some form of double negation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ironically enough, I actually was looking for the word to describe it. I think you are correct about litotes. Perhaps "not inappropriate" could be considered one, but "not appropriate" doesn't seem to fit the definition. Negation is a more accurate description.

Comment: "Not inappropriate" is definitely litotes, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps ***insensitive*** (for the person sitting too close) or ***inconsiderate*** (for the garrulous subordinate).

***Insensitive*** - destitute of, or wanting in, mental or moral sensitiveness; having no quickness of feeling; not susceptible of impression.

***Inconsiderate*** - not characterised by consideration; acting without deliberation; thoughtless, imprudent, indiscreet, careless; without consideration or regard for the circumstances, claims, feelings, etc. of others.

(definitions from OED).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [@Richard Kayser](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191609/richard-kayser)'s sentiment that **inappropriate** is a perfectly acceptable word. However, if you really want to avoid using it, and are looking for something that might be interpreted more mildly by your audience, and as suggested by others, you might consider **improper**, **incorrect**, **unfitting**, or **indiscreet**.

---

<sub>That said, I'd like to also throw in **[unseemly](https://www.google.fi/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aunseemly)**, which is a delightful word that has a quaint, almost archaic air of 19th-century nobility to it (think of [Jane Austin](https://www.bl.uk/voices-of-science/britishlibrary/~/media/bl/global/english-online/video%20images/still-video-austen-class-marriage.jpg?w=560&h=315)). It can be used in the following way: *During the meeting, the financial analyst was sitting far too close to me, in an **unseemly** manner.*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

What about *questionable*? Definitely less extreme than inappropriate, but still manages to convey the meaning that people would raise questions about the propriety of the thing under discussion.

Example: "Their conduct during the meeting was questionable."

Answer (score 0):

You could try **unadvised**, or **ill-advised.**

## Unadvised

This carries a similar feeling as inappropriate but with less intensity. It avoids the common connotation you speak of.

#### Definition of [**unadvised**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unadvised):

1. done without due consideration :  rash

   - *example*: **unadvised** and dangerous dealings with the terrorists
2. not prudent :  ill-advised

   - *example*: done with **unadvised** haste

## Ill-advised

This term is a little more commonly-used, though it may carry a slightly heavier connotation than *unadvised*, though still far less than *inappropriate*.

#### Definition of [**ill-advised**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ill-advised):

1. not wise or sensible : resulting from or showing lack of wise and sufficient counsel or deliberation

   - *example*: an **ill–advised** decision

## References

1. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unadvised
2. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ill-advised

Answer (score -4):

in·sub·or·di·nate
ˌinsəˈbôrd(ə)nət/
adjective
defiant of authority; disobedient to orders.
"an insubordinate attitude"

Source: Google

If I were an E-1 (Private) in the Marines, and spoke to an E-5 (Sergeant) as though my experience trumps theirs, it would be considered insubordinate behavior.

Comment: My take on the word "uncouth" is that its use would, in most contexts that spring to mind, generate a more extreme connotation than the OP's word "inappropriate".

Comment: Point taken. I've edited the original answer.

Comment: Glad to see that you've now reflected on the matter and pointed out the inappropriateness of the word uncouth in response to the OP's scheme of things. I've rewarded you with a point for being commendably couth in cyberspace. Well done.

Answer (score -4):

How about "awkward" or "graceless"? Maybe "artless"?

Answer (score -5):

Improper? Or not following norms, etiquette?